# How Do I sort an NSMutable Array with NSNumbers in it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays

I'm trying to make a high score table, and suck at arrays in objective c (actually, in general objective c is challenging for me), so I can't figure out how to sort. I'm trying to do something like this (speudocode, I'm writing this in actionscript style because I'm more comfortable with it):

```
highscores.addObjecttoArray(score)
highscores.sort(ascending)
```

But I can't figure it out... I've seen other threads about it, but their use plist files and stuff and I don't know enough objective c to learn from them.

Comment: You should read up on NSPredicate and Predicate Programming topics. Understanding predicates makes a lot of things easier in Obj-c but its not something most initial training resources spend any time one.

Comment: @TechZen, I think you mean NSSortDescriptior?

Comment: Ah, yes. My brain insist on transposing NSSortDescriptior and NSPredicate about half the time. Still my advice was sound if off topic.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Would you like to do that the short way?

If you have a mutable array of `NSNumber` instances:

```
NSSortDescriptor *highestToLowest = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self" ascending:NO];
[mutableArrayOfNumbers sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:highestToLowest]];
```

Nice and easy :)

You can also perform similar sorting with descriptors on immutable arrays, but you will end up with a copy, instead of in-place sorting.

Comment: Nice and Easy baby ;)

Comment: For clarification (and optimisation): `NSSortDescriptor *highestToLowest = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self" ascending:NO];
                NSArray * sortedArray = [mutArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[highestToLowest]];`

Comment: A sort descriptor is typically working with instances of objects that need sorting. You specify the key to be a property of the object used for ordering. If it were instances of say "People" class, you might use a key of `"firstName"`. In this case the `NSNumber` object has no properties to be specified as the key, so a special property `"self"` is used for reference to the value of the number itself!

Answer (score 28):

`[highscores sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];`

Should work if they're definitely all `NSNumber`s.

(Adding an object is:

`[highscores addObject:score];`

)

If you want to sort descending (highest-first):

10.6/iOS 4:

```
[highscores sortUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    if (obj1 > obj2)
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    else if (obj1 < obj2)
        return NSOrderedDescending;

    return NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

Otherwise you can define a category method, e.g.:

```
@interface NSNumber (CustomSorting)

- (NSComparisonResult)reverseCompare:(NSNumber *)otherNumber;

@end

@implementation NSMutableArray (CustomSorting)

- (NSComparisonResult)reverseCompare:(NSNumber *)otherNumber {
    return [otherNumber compare:self];
}

@end
```

And call it:

`[highscores sortUsingSelector:@selector(reverseCompare:)];`

Comment: Ok, minor problem, I think thats sorting it the wrong way... Is their anyway to switch that around?

Comment: you mean ascending and descending?

Comment: You said ascending in the question, but I'll edit it with extra info. :)

Comment: I always get ascending and descending mixed up, thanks for the help.

Comment: (Don't forget to accept the answer if it answers your question! ;) )

Comment: @Wevah, while it is very educational to use categories or blocks, there are sorting mechanisms (`NSSortDescriptor`) for simple ordering like this case.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the answer provided by ohhorob, but the objects were still being sorted alphabetically.  Then I ran across this in another answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4550451/823356):

I changed my NSSortDescriptor and it now sorts numerically.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"score"
                                               ascending:YES
                                              comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSNumericSearch];
}];
```

I just thought I'd drop this in here as it solved my 'alphabetical sorting of NSNumbers' problem

Answer (score 2):

For all it's worth, here is another shorthand method:

```
NSArray* n = @[@8, @3, @1, @12, @16, @7, @0, @5];

NSArray* asc = [n sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSNumber* n1, NSNumber* n2) {
            return [n1 compare:n2];
        }];
NSLog(@"Ascending: %@", asc);

NSArray* dec = [n sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSNumber* n1, NSNumber* n2) {
           return [n2 compare:n1];
       }];
NSLog(@"Descending: %@", dec);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will sort an NSMutableArray of NSNumber in ascending order:

```
[tempRA sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [obj1 compare:obj2];
}];
```

This code will sort an NSMutableArray of NSNumber in descending order:

```
[tempRA sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [obj1 compare:obj2] * -1; // reverse the enum
}];
```

The code uses the fact that the NSNumber compare: method returns an NSComparisonResult that ranges from -1 to 1. Multiplying the result of the compare by -1 reverses the result and thereby reverses the sort to descending order.

Comment: or you can change `[obj1 compare:obj2]` with `[n2 compare:n1]`

Answer (score 0):

distance is a key and it's value link (float or double)

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"distance"
ascending:YES
comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2)
                     {
                  return [obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSNumericSearch];
                     }];
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:arraySubCat];
myArray=[myArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor,nil]];
arraySubCat = [myArray copy];
```

Answer (score -1):

For **Descending** Order:

```
NSArray *DescendingArray = [MinMaxArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
                                @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"doubleValue"
                                                                ascending:NO]]];
```

For ascending Order

```
NSArray *AscendingArray = [MinMaxArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
                                @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"doubleValue"
                                                                ascending:YES]]];
```