# How to sort numbers in array from low to high

Tags: iphone, sdk, iphone-sdk-4.1

I am trying to sort an array of prices from low to high. I have it working but not the way I want it to. Long story short, the sorter is putting numbers in order like this:
100
10900
200
290

instead of sorting like this

100
200
290
10900

here is my code I am doing this with.

```
-(void)filterPriceLowHigh {
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
    sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"ListPrice"
        ascending:YES] autorelease];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
    NSArray *sortedArray;
    sortedArray = [app.vehiclesArrayToDisplay
        sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    [app.vehiclesArrayToDisplay removeAllObjects];
    [app.vehiclesArrayToDisplay addObjectsFromArray:sortedArray];
}
```

Could someone tell me what I need to do here? 
thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't want to be Captain Obvious, but the numbers are sorted like strings. Did you check the datatype of that field?

Comment: yes the "listprice" is a string - what would i need to do/convert in order to get them to sort the way i want?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create the sort descriptor like this:

```
sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"ListPrice"
                                               ascending:YES
                                              comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSNumericSearch];
}];
```

Comment: Excellent!! thanks for this... i thought id definitely have to convert my string but not with this chunk of code. - thanks again.

Comment: Btw, you can sort `vehiclesArrayToDisplay` in place with `-sortUsingDescriptors:`. No need to create a separate NSArray.

Comment: @OleBegemann Unfortunately, I can't use SortDescriptor with comparator in CoreData FetchRequest :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your NSString's to NSNumbers first. Look at the documentation for `NSNumberFormatter` and the instance method `numberFromString`.