# Sorting Numbers Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nslog, nsnumber

I want to make a demo app where I can enter 4 numbers into the code and it sort it in 1,2,3 order and will `NSLog` it for me. Is there an easy algorithm or a way to do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you tried out some books tutorials to get the basics down?

Comment: It's great that you want to learn Objective-C. For one thing, it's a rare skill which means that when you're an adult looking for a job, people will be willing to pay you more money. :) But you need to put effort into it yourself first, and that means reading every book you can find about C, Objective-C, and the concepts involved. (Oh, and take as many math classes as you can in high school and college/uni, especially algebra. Yes, you'll use algebra in the real world, I promise.)

Comment: I have read a lot about NSMutableArrays and other Obective-C Documentaions and have searched a lot for answers before posting this.

Comment: @ShalinShah: This is a very basic question. Not to be rude, but you haven't read enough if you're still asking for help with this sort of thing. Keep reading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
// Put code in your App's ViewController
@implementation Sorting_NumbersViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{

[super viewDidLoad];

// CODE STARTS HERE
  // This allocates and initializes the NSMutableArray
  NSMutableArray *anArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  // These are where you enter your numbers
  [anArray addObject:@"1"];
  [anArray addObject:@"3"];
  [anArray addObject:@"2"];

  //This looks looks at the objects above and compares them with each-other
  NSArray *sorted = [anArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

  //This spits the result out in the console
  NSLog(@"Ordered Numbers: %@", sorted);  

}
```

Comment: @James the method compare: is called on the NSNumbers in the array. NSNumber declares the method in its interface. He cannot post the compare method implementation because Apple wrote it. See: - (NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSNumber *)otherNumber; from NSNumber: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumber/compare:

Answer (score 5):

`NSMutableArray` has some great sorting methods, as documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Unfortunately this is not a **give me teh codez** site - we want to see you put in a little effort yourself!

Comment: I have spent 2 whole days figuring out how to make this work, I was aking for the code so that I could learn what other people were thinking and how they wrote the code for this.

Comment: show us what you've done so far.

Comment: look at my answer on the bottom

Answer (score 0):

As Luke wrote, there are some great sorting methods built into `NSMutableArray`.  You will learn a lot more if you implement the algorithms yourself, however.  Check out [Bubble Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).  It is one type of sorting algorithm that should serve you well in this task, and is a great thing to understand regardless.

EDIT: Check out this [StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205792/how-do-i-sort-an-nsmutable-array-with-nsnumbers-in-it).  I literally just googled "sort `NSMutableArray` of `NSNumber`s" and this was one of the first hits.

Comment: I would recommend against bubble sort. It's much harder to understand than a [`merge sort`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) or [`quick sort`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), and bubble sort encourages you to sort things in the slowest possible way.

Comment: @user1118321 that's a fair point.  Still not a bad thing to understand, imo.  Either way, I think my basic sentiment that learning how it works at this point in the game is more valuable than being able to just make it work in one language.